# how to use MHI and MEI for action recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, activity-recognition, surveillance

I'm currently working on a project to recognise human action / activity through Matlab for elderly surveillance.

I'm reading up on different paper to understand how to recognise these action and I have across motion history image and motion energy image to do the template matching. I've seen the result of the MHI and MEI but after getting these result, how do you actually use them to recognise image on a surveillance video? Thank you for helping in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use resultant Motion History Images(MHI) for training a classifier like normal images. Different classification approaches can serve the purpose say Bag of words etc